# Access folder in remote linux system from client and display documents on client browser

Tags: java, linux, display

I need to access a folder present in a Linux server (Cent OS 6) so that my Java code running in another server is able access it, search through the files in that directory and display it in the browser (through my Java web application running on client). Can some one please help me on this. Kindly let me know if any other info is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Insufficient data , could you please explain what u tried so far ?

Comment: I am able to display a document that I hosted online through iframe. But since I'm new to this, I am not able to decide if I should use SCP SSH NFS or SSHFS for my case, since I don't need to copy/download anything, i just need a list of filenames from where the user will select the file and then, display the selected file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you **must** have a service/daemon on the server which you can connect to.
It can be port 22 then you can use ssh

NOTE: you can also use scp but then you will force the client to download each and every file he wants to see. **But** recall it might won't be displayed if he uses mobile phone.

Displaying the file in an iframe sounds like a simple idea.

If I were you I would implement it in an iframe or redirect to the file in server (require a lot of work on the remote server in order to protect him) or pull the file to my server and cache it so the user will see the cached file.

if you are talking about browsing files' names then ssh would be enough.
otherwise I need more information